# How can I load multiple YAML files in rails application.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, yaml

I have many yaml files in config/ And I want to load all yaml files.

EX: I have two .yml files name is: `application.yml` and `linkedin.yml`. I want to load both files with `application.rb`.

To achieve this goal I Have written code in application.rb:

```
ENV.update YAML.load_file('config/application.yml')[Rails.env] rescue {}
ENV.update YAML.load_file('config/linkedin.yml')[Rails.env] rescue {}
```

But this is not appropriate way, Please suggest me how can I load all yaml files access with `ENV` variable that.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your YAML files are placed in the `config` folder, in your application.rb you can do this right under the requires (before the module definition)

```
APP_YAML = YAML::load_file(File.join(File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__)), 'application.yml'))
LINKED_IN = YAML::load_file(File.join(File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__)), 'linked_in.yml'))
```

This way, you can then access the contents of the file in a constant that is available everywhere in the app ie. `LINKED_IN["secret"]`

This is a great way to handle constants that you don't want to check in to source control, but actually I've found that using [Figaro](https://github.com/laserlemon/figaro) is the best way to handle constants. Essentially, Figaro will autogenerate/load an application.yml and all you have to do is put your constants in there.

After this, you can access with ENV["LINKED_IN_SECRET"] - as a plus, this emulates how Heroku would do it with their config:set variable system so you don't have to worry about environment changes :)